# scrapy exception CloseSpider to close spider function

Tags: python, scrapy

What happens when "CloseSpider" exception is thrown and how I can I deal with.

```
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider
    #code
    def parse(self,response):
        #code
        if condition:
            raise CloseSpider(reason="bandwidth_exceed")


    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
        spider = super(FlickrSearchSpider, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.spider_closed, signal=scrapy.signals.spider_closed)
        return spider
    def spider_closed(self):
        print("completed")
```

How can I distinguish spider_closed from normal run or from condition met (`reason="bandwidth_exceed"`). I want to be able to handle each differently if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple, just define `closed`:

```
def closed(self, reason):
    if reason == "bandwidth_exceed":
        process_bandwidth_exceed()
    else:
        something_else()
    pass
```

Comment: thanks, It doesn't mention in docs that I can call "self,reason" in closing function